# Query document and select subdocument

Tags: select, go, mgo, subdocument

I want to select a subdocument using mgo.
Before select, the query should query the right top level document.
I tried this:

```
name := "anything"
w := models.Wallet{}
c := s.DB("ep2").C("users")
err := c.Find(bson.M{"name": name}).Select(bson.M{"wallet": 1}).One(&w)
```

These are the structs:

```
type User struct {
    Id     bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"-" form:"-"`
    Wallet Wallet        `bson:"wallet,omitempty" json:"wallet,omitempty" form:"wallet,omitempty"`
} 

type Wallet struct {
    Taddr     string  `json:"taddr,omitempty" form:"taddr,omitempty"`
    TaddrPriv string  `json:"-" form:"-"`
    Tbalance  float64 `json:"tbalance" form:"tbalance,omitempty"`
}
```

It returns an empty wallet document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`Query.Select()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Select) you may specify which fields of the queried document(s) you want to retrieve, but the retrieved entities **will not be the values of the selected fields, they will still be the values of the queried documents!**

So since you are querying the `"users"` collection, you should pass a value of `*User` to [`Query.One()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.One):

```
name := "anything"
u := models.User{}
c := s.DB("ep2").C("users")
err := c.Find(bson.M{"name": name}).Select(bson.M{"wallet": 1}).One(&u)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    return
}

// Wallet is in u.Wallet
fmt.Printf("Result wallet: %+v", u.Wallet)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to only receive wallet? Maybe sth. like add wallet collection and set a foreign key to User?

Comment: @nayD93 The query above only retrieves the wallet wrapped in a user (plus the user id). If even this bothers you, you may use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) where it's possible to project the returned data, and then you could retrieve only the wallet, unwrapped, without the user id. See [`Collection.Pipe()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Pipe) as a starting point.

Comment: @nayD93 And of course splitting wallet into its own collection and querying that is also a viable option.